# automate mysql mysql_secure_installation script but not as expected

Tags: mysql

mysql is  5.7.34  ubuntu  18.04

Script I wrote    my.sh

```
#!/usr/bin/expect

spawn  mysql_secure_installation


expect {
             "Press y|Y for Yes, any other key for No" { send "n\r"; exp_continue }
             "New password" { send "123456\r"; exp_continue }
             "Re-enter new password" { send "123456\r"; exp_continue }
             "Remove anonymous users?" { send "y\r"; exp_continue }
             "Disallow root login remotely" { send "n\r"; exp_continue }
             "Remove test database and access to it" { send "Y\r"; exp_continue }
             "Reload privilege tables now" { send "Y\r"; exp_continue }
     }
```

./my.sh

The results of the operation are as follows

Why the script did not execute as expected

```
root@fa244a50dc06:/# ./my.sh
spawn mysql_secure_installation

Securing the MySQL server deployment.

Connecting to MySQL using a blank password.

VALIDATE PASSWORD PLUGIN can be used to test passwords
and improve security. It checks the strength of password
and allows the users to set only those passwords which are
secure enough. Would you like to setup VALIDATE PASSWORD plugin?

Press y|Y for Yes, any other key for No: n
Please set the password for root here.

New password:

Re-enter new password:
By default, a MySQL installation has an anonymous user,
allowing anyone to log into MySQL without having to have
a user account created for them. This is intended only for
testing, and to make the installation go a bit smoother.
You should remove them before moving into a production
environment.

Remove anonymous users? (Press y|Y for Yes, any other key for No) : n

 ... skipping.


Normally, root should only be allowed to connect from
'localhost'. This ensures that someone cannot guess at
the root password from the network.

Disallow root login remotely? (Press y|Y for Yes, any other key for No) : n

 ... skipping.
By default, MySQL comes with a database named 'test' that
anyone can access. This is also intended only for testing,
and should be removed before moving into a production
environment.


Remove test database and access to it? (Press y|Y for Yes, any other key for No) : n

 ... skipping.
Reloading the privilege tables will ensure that all changes
made so far will take effect immediately.

Reload privilege tables now? (Press y|Y for Yes, any other key for No) : n

 ... skipping.
All done!
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first line in your `expect` is overriding everything else:

```
Press y|Y for Yes, any other key for No
```

This string is matched with every line, so `send "n\r"; exp_continue` will be run. Hence all of the `n` responses.

The simplest solution would likely be to put this line at the end of the `expect` array so that it acts as a default catch-all.

Comment: thanks for your answer,I selected the wrong match

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/usr/bin/expect

spawn  mysql_secure_installation


expect {
             "VALIDATE PASSWORD PLUGIN can be used to test passwords" { send "n\r"; exp_continue }
             "New password" { send "123456\r"; exp_continue }
             "Re-enter new password" { send "123456\r"; exp_continue }
             "Remove anonymous users?" { send "y\r"; exp_continue }
             "Disallow root login remotely" { send "n\r"; exp_continue }
             "Remove test database and access to it" { send "Y\r"; exp_continue }
             "Reload privilege tables now" { send "Y\r"; exp_continue }
        }
```